# How to create readonly table from raw data

Tags: database, libreoffice, libreoffice-calc, query

If I have a large table of data, essentially like a database, can I create another sheet or range that is a filtered subset of the full dataset? If so, will it stay up to date when the main table changes?

Can a third table be the subset of a second following another filtering?

Could a fourth essentially be a query of multiple tables?

Would it be possible to make those tables writable and that updates the original table?

In a way, how close can one get to a full on poor-man's database inside Libreoffice Calc?

Comment: You do know that LibreOffice [comes with a database](https://www.libreoffice.org/discover/base/)?

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad I am, though its storage file format seems to not be compatible with any other system, nor can it be programmed against outside of libreoffice, I don't know how I would ever make an export to a more mature system, and it lacks many basic functions of a proper database. Once I've proven the concept of what I'm trying to do, then I would reimplement in MySQL and port the data over.